Ошибка при попытке сохранить сущность EntityFramework
Делаю приложение на C# + WindowsForms .NET Framework 4.8 .
Использую при этом EntityFramework и PostgreSQL.
Вот код:
public partial class TransactionForm : Form
{
    private FinancialSystem _financialSystem;
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public TransactionForm(FinancialSystem financialSystem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        InitData();
        _financialSystem = financialSystem;
    }

    private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var date = datePicker.Value;
        var amount = Convert.ToDecimal(amountBox.Text);
        var contragent = contrAgentBox.Text;
        var type = (TransactionType)typeBox.SelectedItem;
        var category = (Category)categoryBox.SelectedItem;

        var transaction = new Transaction
        {
            Date = date,
            Amount = amount,
            Contragent = contragent,
            Type = type,
            CategoryId = category.Id,
            FinancialSystem = _financialSystem
        };

        _context.Transactions.Add(transaction);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        _context.Dispose();

        Close();
    }

    private void InitData()
    {
        var categories = _context.Categories.ToList();
        categoryBox.DataSource = categories;
        typeBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TransactionType));
    }
}

При попытке сохранить транзакцию

_context.Transactions.Add(transaction)

вылазит вот такая ошибка:

System.InvalidOperationException: "The instance of entity type
'Category' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same
key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing
entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value
is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.Enable Sensitive
Data Logging' to see the conflicting key values."

С чем это связано? Я вроде бы один контекст использую во всем коде, так же пытался передавать лишь ID, все равно эта ошибка.

что такое _financialSystem? type?

@tym32167 объект и енамка. Я подумал к вопросу не относится, ибо не в этом ошибка.

подкажите ваши модели данных. У вас ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь оперировать сущностями которые были прочитаны другим контекстом. Попробуйте убрать строчку FinancialSystem = _financialSystem

Вместо CategoryId = category.Id, напишите Category = category. Если такого свойства нет, сделайте его.

@tym32167  спасибо. Дело было в том, что я как раз прокидывал объект FinancialSystem, который получал на предыдущей форме из другого контекста.

@AlexanderPetrov спасибо, вроде бы разобрался.
